# How to "see" audio files in binary format?

Tags: java

I have an AAC file. I want to see the audio file in a binary format.

I want to apply certain functions to the data and hear what it sounds like. I also want to extract the MDCT coefficients.

Comment: Have you checked the Java Sound API? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [JSymphonic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/symphonic/) can help you.